# Postgres - only return results of query if two sub-queries produce results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is a table called `fruits`:

```
id  fruit_name  quantity   date
1 | 'apple'    | 10       | '2019-01-01'
2 | 'peach'    | 15       | '2019-01-02'
3 | 'plum'     | 5        | '2019-01-05'
4 | 'banana'   | 10       | '2019-01-06'
5 | 'orange'   | 20       | '2019-01-06'
6 | 'grape'    | 25       | '2019-01-09'
```

I'm trying to create a query from two sub-queries. The main query should only return results if *both* the two sub-queries each returned any results. So if either of the two sub-queries does not have any results, then the query as a whole should return nothing.

The following is a query I've worked on. It sorta gets at what I am trying to create:

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM fruits
    WHERE fruit_name = ('pear')
)
SELECT *
FROM r
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit_name = ('banana')
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM r
  );
```

So this query will *not* return any results, because the first sub-query asks for a 'pear', and there is no 'pear' in the `fruits` table. This is working *as intended*.

However, if I swap 'pear' and 'banana' in the query, then it will return one row: the 'banana' row. This is not what I want happen -- in this scenario, I would also want it to return *nothing*.

So basically, how can I modify this query (or use a better query) so that it only returns results *if* each of the two sub-queries *each* have results?

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7ecb1/5

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve with this. However, you get the 'banana' output in your second example, because you use an `SELECT * FROM r UNION ALL ...`! This gives you all the results from your common table expression (your first subquery) everytime. So just leave this out!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two checks in the where clause:

```
select *
from fruits
where fruit_name in ('banana', 'pear')
and exists (
    select from fruits
    where fruit_name = 'banana')
and exists (
    select from fruits
    where fruit_name = 'pear');
```

Note that in Postgres the select list may be empty. You can select a column or a constant

```
...
and exists (
    select id from fruits
    where fruit_name = 'banana')
...
```

but this does not affect the result.

Alternatively, you can check whether the results contain rows with both `banana` and `pear`:

```
with results as (
    select *
    from fruits
    where fruit_name in ('banana', 'pear')
)
select *
from results
where (
    select count(distinct fruit_name)
    from results
    ) = 2
```

Comment: While I agree that this is more efficient and concise than mine in this context, I'm not sure if this is what is wanted. The fact that the look up is on one table is a result of the minimum reproducible example in my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can express using a single subquery:

```
select f.*
from fruits f
where f.fruit_name in ('banana', 'pear') and
      exists (select 1
              from fruits f2
              where f2.fruit_name in ('banana', 'pear') and
                    f2.fruit_name <> f.fruit_name
             );
```

However, assuming that the name is unique, I would be inclined to do:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*, count(*) over () as cnt
      from fruits f
      where f.fruit_name in ('banana', 'pear')
     ) f
where cnt = 2;
```

This logic can easily be adjusted if you do have duplicates, but you sample data does not have any.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two sub-queries instead of one

```
WITH sub1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM fruits
    WHERE fruit_name = ('pear')
),
sub2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM fruits
    WHERE fruit_name = ('banana')
)
SELECT *
FROM sub1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM sub2
WHERE
EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sub1
  )
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sub2
  );
```

Comment: Any reason why this is downvoted, the question mentions explicitly that it has be two subqueries, `only return results of query if two sub-queries produce results`

Comment: "However, if I swap 'pear' and 'banana' in the query, then it will return one row: the 'banana' row. This is not what I want happen -- in this scenario, I would also want it to return nothing."

This is exactly what happens in your example!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how this behaves. xD